# How to replace special character, and then store that into a shell variable?

Tags: shell, unix, emacs

I'm doing some script shell work, and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. The code

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='
'
sed s/"$1"/"$2"/g "$3" > "$3.updated"
mv "$3.updated" $3
```

Is a shell script named "sub1". Sub1 is passed three variables; a string to be replaced ($1), a string which replaces it ($2), and the name of the file ($3). I am attempting to modify the above code so that if the character to be replaced is a "special character", (like * or / or .), I can replace it into a 'safe' version (i.e "*" if the character was a *)

My code is as follows.

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS='
'

"$1" = $target
sed 's/*//*/g' "$target" > "$newtarget"
"$1" ="$newtarget"
sed s/"$1"/"$2"/g "$3" > "$3.updated"
mv "$3.updated" $3
```

However, when the following command is entered to test my code (./sub2 * x testcase2), testcase2 merely containing the text "test*test", I get the following errors.

```
 ./sub2: 5: ./sub2: 252225688.dat: not found
 ./sub2: 6: ./sub2: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
 ./sub2: 7: ./sub2: 25225688.dat: not found
```

I'm very confused as to the reasoning behind these errors; 252225788.dat isn't called in my code (though it is in the same directory as my sub2 script), so I have no clue why that would even be a problem. I opened up 252225788 with emacs to see what it contained, and it was only the text "%%%%%%%%". I'm very confused as to what I'm supposed to be doing here. At first I thought it was just my syntax, but the whole deal with 252225688 has thrown me off completely.

EDIT:
What I'm trying to do is that the $1 parameter could have a number of 'unsafe' characters in it (i.e., [, ], ., *, ). The parameter could just be something like "*", it could be "L*", it could be "w\o\r\d\". I'm told I should put the target string ($1 parameter) into a shell variable, $target like I did, and then use a sed command to rewrite those characters ([,],^, *, those ones) into safe versions by either adding backslashes in front, or surrounding them by []. I would then store that rewritten version of the string into another shell variable ($newtarget). I assumed I would go about the actual replacement (sed, rewriting the shell variable) with my "sed 's/"*"/"/*"/g'" deal, but apparently that's not the right way to go about it.

Comment: In addition to needing to quote a `*` on the command line as @pfnuesel said, there are a couple of errors. Inside a shell script, `$1` is replaced by the first argument you gave to the shell script. It's unlikely you want this on the left hand side of an assignment statement. Did you perhaps mean to write `target="$3"`? (Don't put any spaces between the variable and the =). Also, * is special to `sed`. Can you tell us what `s/*//*/g` is supposed to do? We'll help you rewrite it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see this earlier s/*//*/g is supposed to find instances of the "*" character, and replace it with "/*", since I assumed that was how I did it syntax wise. And for the $1 bit, I just need the $target to be equal to the $1 parameter, do what I need to with $target, save that to $newtarget, and then save the value back over to $1

Comment: Edited my main question.

Comment: You need to quote special regular expression characters in sed, so use `sed 's/\*/\//g'` . Shell assignments are of the form `variable=value`. No spaces around the =. No $ in front of variable unless you want to use its contents. You can't assign to $1 inside shell scripts (you can use the `set` command to see a new arument list, but you don't need that here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is expanded by the shell to the list of files in your current directory, this is called glob expansion or globbing. Try

```
$ echo *
> file1
> file2
...
```

If you want to echo `*`, you need to escape it

```
$ echo \*
> *
```

or put it in quotes

```
$ echo "*"
> *
$ echo '*'
> *
```

Another option is to turn off glob expansion

```
$ set -f
$ echo *
> *
```

but unlikely that you want that, since glob expansion is a good thing.

So if you want to pass `*` as a character to a script of yours, escape it or put quotes around it.